# Implementing ngClassEven ngClassOdd for angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-ng-class-even, angularjs-ng-class-odd

I tried to implement ng-class-even and ng-class-odd ( from angular 1) type behaviour in angular 2 application.

I have written the code below and its working fine, I want to know if there is any other way of doing this.

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="#employee of employees; #index = index" [class.odd]="index%2==1" [class.even]="index%2==0" [class.selected]="employee === selectedEmployee"> 
      <p>{{employee.name}}</p>
         </div>
```

CSS

```
.odd {
    background-color: #f2f9ff;

}
.even {
    background-color: #eceff3;
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**OLD way**
**DEMO** : http://plnkr.co/edit/YkcudQipF1c8iT5LCRyd?p=preview

```
<div *ngFor="#employee of employees; 
             #index =index;
             #isOdd=odd;
             #isEven=even" 

     [class.odd]="isOdd" 
     [class.even]="isEven" 
     [class.selected]="employee === selectedEmployee"> 
     <p>{{employee.name}}</p>
</div>
```

---

**New Way**

replace **`#`** by **`let`**(keyword)

```
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees; 
             let index =index;
             let isOdd=odd;
             let isEven=even" 

      [class.odd]="isOdd" 
      [class.even]="isEven" 
      [class.selected]="employee === selectedEmployee"> 
      <p>{{employee.name}}</p>

</div>
```

Comment: This should be updated to get rid of # and use 'let'. Correct usage in latest ng2 is `let isEven=even` etc.

Answer (score 14):

**update (Angular4)**

```ts
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees; index as i; odd as isOdd; even as isEven"
```

**original (Angular2)**

This should work:

```ts
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees; let index = index; let isOdd=odd; let isEven=even" 
    [class.Odd]="isOdd" 
    [class.even]="isEven" 
    [class.selected]="employee === selectedEmployee"> 
      <p>{{employee.name}}</p>
         </div>
```

> `NgFor` provides several exported values that can be aliased to local variables:
>
> - `index` will be set to the current loop iteration for each template context.
> - `first` will be set to a boolean value indicating whether the item is the first one in the iteration. (since beta.15)
> - `last` will be set to a boolean value indicating whether the item is the last one in the iteration.
> - `even` will be set to a boolean value indicating whether this item has an even index.
> - `odd` will be set to a boolean value indicating whether this item has an odd index.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uSZsEH?p=preview)

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: I run into the error myself while creating the plunker. These variables need assignment like `#index=index`.

Comment: <div class="post" *ngFor="#shaer of shaers; #index = index;#odd=odd;#even=even" [class.odd]="odd" [class.even]="even"> 

This worked 

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
<div *ngFor="#employee of employees; #index = index;#isOdd=odd;#isEven=even" 
    [class.Odd]="isOdd" 
    [class.even]="isEven" 
    [class.selected]="employee === selectedEmployee"> 
      <p>{{employee.name}}</p>
         </div>
```

The above code worked fine.

Thanks Gunter, micronyks.

Comment: You're supposed to accept the answer which solved your problem.

Comment: Accepted 

Thanks for letting me know , was not aware though ;)