# How can I break from an *ngFor loop in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, templates, ngfor

How can I break from an *ngFor loop in Angular 4?

I just want this loop to break after it executes once.

```
  <div *ngFor="let thing of things">
    <div *ngIf="thing == otherThing">
      <h4>Sub Title</h4>
      ***BREAK HERE***
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why not do it in code-behind?

Comment: Much more work. I was just hoping there was a more elegant way.

Comment: For me that's the least resistance way to do this sort of thing. I guess it's up to each person though.

Comment: I did end up doing tat... Just sucks lol Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Break NgFor Loop in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911219/break-ngfor-loop-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't break *ngFor.

But you can build a custom pipe to filter the data.

But as Jus10's said, the better way is to do it in ts-file.

Comment: Ya... Seems like a lot of work the way I have it all set up... lol. I guess if it's the only option...

Comment: Did it in TS. Was just hoping there was a better way :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had to break the loop so i followed the following approach.

I don't know whether its helpful or not still sharing that piece of code.

As ausutine mentioned:

> You can't break *ngFor.

It's just an alternate way to do so.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="i < 10">
        <span> product.name </span>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: it doesn't break the loop, it keeps on iterating over products array. But, in the practice it does the job, though not so efficiently

Comment: You are absolutely right Leon. Highlighted point says the same that you can't break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this slice, scenario (you want to run loop for n elements)

```
<div *ngFor="let thing of things.slice(0,1)">
<div *ngIf="thing == otherThing">
  <h4>Sub Title</h4>
</div>
```