# Angular 2 - set attribute of list item according to component variable

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I have a list of items and when the page loads I want the first item to look active.

```
<li *ngFor="let link of links; let i = index;" (click)="setActive(i)" class="{i === activeIndex ? 'active' : ''}">
    <a routerLink="{{link.url}}">{{link.text}}</a>
</li>
```

and the class looks like this

```
export class NavbarComponent{
    private links: Array<Object>;
    private activeIndex: number = 0;

    constructor(private linksService: LinksService) {
        this.links = linksService.getNavLinks();
    }

    setActive(index: number) {
        this.activeIndex = index;
    }
}
```

The list item becomes active correctly on clicking it. But not when the page loads. What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `first` variable provided by `ngFor` and use `[class.xxx]="..."` binding to set/remove a class:

```ts
<li *ngFor="let link of links; let i = index" 
     [class.active]="activeIndex == i" 
     (click)="setActive(i)">
    <a routerLink="{{link.url}}">{{link.text}}</a>
</li>
```

See also [Implementing ngClassEven ngClassOdd for angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314261/implementing-ngclasseven-ngclassodd-for-angular-2/36314281#36314281)

Comment: @micronyks if you remove `{{}}` you need to add at least `[]`. When `link.url` returns a string (not an array) then `{{}}` is fine as well.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but now it messes up my setActive function and it stays always active. Can you please guide me on changing this function?

Comment: I see. In this case you can't use `first`. I updated my answer.